# Magento Product Availability -> Cannot find code on configurable products

Tags: file, magento, find, php

So I am trying to throw in a little catchy code to the Product Availability section on our Magento product pages to add the the "Availability: In Stock" portion.

If the item is backordered I want to add some additional code.  The code is not my problem, I can't find where to put it.

With simple products I simply edit:

```
template/catalog/product/view/type/simple.phtml
```

Now one with common sense would presume that a configurable product with children products could be found in

```
template/catalog/product/view/type/configurable.phtml
```

But of course with Magento, this would make too much sense.  Essentially could someone show me how to edit the availability/price area of the page for a configurable product with children?

Many thanks!

Comment: Which version of Magento are you using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May I recommend that you enable template path hints? Admin > System > Configuration > Developer (all the way at the bottom) > Debug. You'll need to switch out of the default configuration scope to see the template path hints options. Once this is enabled, flush the cache and you should see the files being used when you refresh the catalog product view page.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know about that option that's great! So I found that it accesses  `template/catalog/product/view/type/configurable.phtml` just like I thought.  Then why am I not able to edit this area of the product page like I am for simple.phtml?

Comment: Oops! Figured it out.  Problem resolved.  Thanks Ben Marks for the tip that will help out alot in my debugging in the future!

Comment: No problem. I provide a lot of similar tips in the week-long Magento U Fundamentals of Magento Development course. Most of Magento development is learning how to help yourself!